# How to underline text using print and format

Tags: python, formatting

I have a pretty basic python formatting question. I am trying to get all the strings in the following code to be underlined. I have the following code.

```
print("\u0332{:<20} {:^5} {:>6} {:>10} {:>10}\u0332".format("Name", "Hours Worked", "Hourly Rate", "Taxes Owed", "Net Pay"))
```

It puts out this:

```
_Name                 Hours Worked Hourly Rate Taxes Owed    Net Pay̲
```

How do I get it so all are underlined?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
print("\u0332".join('{:<20} {:^5} {:>6} {:>10} {:>10}'.format("Name", "Hours Worked", "Hourly Rate", "Taxes Owed", "Net Pay")))
```

**Edit:** For each word, a simple list comprehension should do.

```
words = ["Name", "Hours Worked", "Hourly Rate", "Taxes Owed", "Net Pay"]
words = ["\u0332".join(word+' ')[:-1] for word in words]
print('{:<20} {:^5} {:>6} {:>10} {:>10}'.format(*words))
```

Comment: Thanks but it underlines the entire section. Ideally, I would just like to have each word underlined.

Comment: Alright, edited in the code for just underlining words.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\u0332`, I would define a function

```
from itertools import repeat, chain


def underline(s):
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(s, repeat("\u0332"))))
```

Then write

```
heads = ["Name", "Hours Worked", "Hourly Rate", "Taxes Owed", "Net Pay"]
print("{:<20} {:^5} {:>6} {:>10} {:>10}".format(*map(underline, heads)))
```

`underline` turns a string like `"Name"` into the string `"N\u0332a\u0332m\u0332e\u0332"`, that is, it adds the combining underline character after *each* character of the string to underline.

---

If your terminal supports ANSI escape codes, consider something like

```
def underline(s):
  return f'\x1b[4m{s}\x1b[24m'
```

instead. This simply enables your terminal's underline mode while the given string is printed, rather than requiring font support for Unicode glyph composition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def undaline(strng):
    undlined = ''
    for char in strng:
        undlined += char + "\u0332"
    return undlined

words = ["Name", "Hours Worked", "Hourly Rate", "Taxes Owed", "Net Pay"]
for index, word in enumerate(words):  # creates list of each word in the list underlined
    words[index] = undaline(word)
```